# The settings64.bat is not getting executed from jenkins shell

Tags: ssh, jenkins

I have an expect script test.exp . 
which is executing from a jenkins shell
What it is doing is, just ssh to a windows pc and execute settings64.bat from its path

1) i can succesfully execute the test.exp from a linux terminal without any issues
2) But when I execute the same from a jenkins shell it couldn't execute the settings64.bat
3) Also the console showing some junk charecters after ssh to the windows system

```
{

spawn ssh lab-user01@lab-pcw202
lab-user01@lab-pcw202's password: 
[H[J[1;1H[37m[40m                             [0;1H
[1;1H                             [1;1H.7601][0;1H
[1;1H                             [0;1H
[1;1H                             [0;1H
[1;1H                             [1;1Hed.[0;1H
[1;1H                             [0;1H
[1;1H                             [1;1HC:\Users\lab-user01>[0;1H
[1;1H                             [1;1HC:\Users\lab-user01>cd \[0;1H
[1;1H                             [0;1H
[1;1H                             [1;1HC:\>cd C:Xilinx\14.4\SDK\[0;1H
[1;1H                             [0;1H
[1;1H                             [1;1HC:\Xilinx\14.4\SDK>settings64[0;1H
[1;1H                             [0;1H
[1;1H                             [1;1H:\Xilinx\14.4\SDK>bat[0;1H
[1;1H                             [0;1H
[1;1H                             [1;1Hinternal or external command,[0;1H
[1;1H                             [0;1H
[1;1H                             [1;1H.[0;1H
}
```

Facing the same with other scripts too. the script is working with linux terminal but not from jenkins

The jenkins shows some junk characters and the lines are splitted. 
for the below example the command that used is cd /sreenitha/sample that was a single command but in jenkins console it shows as splitted

```
[1;1H                              [1;1HC:\Xilinx\SDK\2015.3\bin>cd s[0;1H
[1;1H                              [0;1H
[1;1H                              [1;1H:\Xilinx\SDK\2015.3\bin>/sree[0;1H
[1;1H                              [0;1H
[1;1H                              [1;1H:\Xilinx\SDK\2015.3\bin>itha/[0;1H
[1;1H                              [0;1H
[1;1H                              [1;1H:\Xilinx\SDK\2015.3\bin>ample[0;1H
[1;1H                              [0;1H
[1;1H                              [0;1H
```

Comment: that "junk" are ANSI escape sequences, they're there to do colors and other "formatting" on text. plus, if you'll note, you've got `settings64` and `bat` on two separate command lines there. somehow `settings64.bat` got split into two separate commands, neither of which exists.

Comment: @Marc B                                                                                             Thanks for your replay , Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I am still facing this issue with other script. the script is working from linux terminal but not from jenkins. if the line is long then the line is splitted in to two